# mysql left join or full join with fulltext search results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, titles and contents:

```
headings                           contents

id      title                   p_id  content url  id
```

Now I have this mysql_query:

```
"SELECT id, title FROM headings WHERE 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') ORDER BY 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('$query') DESC"
```

What I wanted to do then is select the content, url from contents after getting the associated id from headings (joining?)....and then order by p_id ascending...Im having difficulty doing this with fulltext search and figuring out how I would join the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT h.title, c.contents, c.url
    FROM headings h
        INNER JOIN contents c
            ON h.id = c.id
    WHERE MATCH (h.title) AGAINST('$query') 
    ORDER BY c.p_id
```

Comment: would i add ASC after order by c.p_id?

Comment: ASC is default, but you can add it if you like.

Comment: sorry another quick question ...how would I also Select the title along with this?

Comment: Just add h.title to the SELECT list. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: I always thought that using a JOIN with FULLTEXT would lose the index and the engine will seek all rows, instead of 1. Is this right?